# Hierarchical table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a problem with creating Hierarchical table, I searched a lot but this problem maybe different from the popular problem.
I have table that need to reconstruct

**The input table :**

```
|       Agency_CODE         |  Code_length       | Agency_Name    
|              1            |       1            |     Boogy
|              11           |       2            |     Elhady
|              12           |       2            |     EzzBatriq
|              13           |       2            |     Haythomy
|              111          |       3            |     Migz
|              121          |       3            |     Mido
|              131          |       3            |     Thabet
```

The hierarchy should be as : The agency which has only one digit is the root of the hierarchy `'Level 1'`, and `level 2` the items which has two digits and `level 3` which has 3 digits. Here we have 3 levels

So we need a query to get this **output**:

```
|Parent_ID |Parent_Name|Child_1_Id|Child_1_name|Child_2_Id|Child_2_name|      
|     1    |   Boogy   |    11    |  Elhady    |  111     |  Migz      |
|     1    |   Boogy   |    12    |  EzzBatriq |  121     |  Mido      | 
|     1    |   Boogy   |    13    |  Haythomy  |  131     |  Thabet    |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your Agency_CODE column CHAR or INT ?

Comment: Agency_Code is VARCHAR

Comment: So what is the rule which explains why `Migz is child of Elhady` and `Mido is child of EzzBatriq`?

Comment: The number of digits is the rule

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea42a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Agencies (
  Agency_CODE NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT Agencies__AC__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Code_length NUMBER(4,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LENGTH( Agency_Code ) ) VIRTUAL,
  Agency_Name VARCHAR2(50),
  parent_code NUMBER(7,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( SUBSTR( Agency_Code, 1, LENGTH( Agency_Code ) - 1 ) ) VIRTUAL
                          CONSTRAINT Agencies__PC__FK REFERENCES Agencies( Agency_Code )
);

INSERT INTO Agencies ( Agency_CODE, Agency_Name )
SELECT   1, 'Boogy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  11, 'Elhady' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  12, 'EzzBatriq' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  13, 'Haythomy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'Migz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 'Mido' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 131, 'Thabet' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Agency_Code ) AS parent_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Agency_name ) AS parent,
       PRIOR( Agency_Code ) AS child_id,
       PRIOR( Agency_name ) AS child,
       Agency_Code AS child2_id,
       Agency_Name AS child2
FROM   Agencies
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
START WITH Code_length = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR Agency_code = parent_code
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea42a/1/0)**:

```
| PARENT_ID | PARENT | CHILD_ID |     CHILD | CHILD2_ID | CHILD2 |
|-----------|--------|----------|-----------|-----------|--------|
|         1 |  Boogy |       11 |    Elhady |       111 |   Migz |
|         1 |  Boogy |       12 | EzzBatriq |       121 |   Mido |
|         1 |  Boogy |       13 |  Haythomy |       131 | Thabet |
```

**Update**: If you know the maximum depth of your nested hierarchy then you can use `PIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2481f/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
INSERT INTO Agencies ( Agency_CODE, Agency_Name )
SELECT 1311, 'Thabet.1' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Agency_Code ) AS leaf_id,
         Agency_Code,
         code_length,
         Agency_Name
  FROM   Agencies a
  START WITH NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   Agencies x
    WHERE  x.parent_code = a.agency_code
  )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_code = Agency_code
) a
PIVOT(
  MAX( agency_code ) AS id,
  MAX( agency_name ) AS name
  FOR code_length IN (
    1 AS parent,
    2 AS child,
    3 AS child1,
    4 AS child2
  )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2481f/13/0)**:

```
| LEAF_ID | PARENT_ID | PARENT_NAME | CHILD_ID | CHILD_NAME | CHILD1_ID | CHILD1_NAME | CHILD2_ID | CHILD2_NAME |
|---------|-----------|-------------|----------|------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|     121 |         1 |       Boogy |       12 |  EzzBatriq |       121 |        Mido |    (null) |      (null) |
|    1311 |         1 |       Boogy |       13 |   Haythomy |       131 |      Thabet |      1311 |    Thabet.1 |
|     111 |         1 |       Boogy |       11 |     Elhady |       111 |        Migz |    (null) |      (null) |
```

Comment: Neat. I was on it, I give up. There can't be any better and elegant solution.

Comment: Really thanks MT0, this is a perfect answer to what I asked, 

Thanks @ThomasG 

... But what if I have  many levels, as I work with dynamic database and each agency contains many ones inside it
example: you maybe find : agency 1 - 11 - 111 - 1111 - ... 11111111
how can I handle this ?

Comment: @MohamedAM-Hassan your sample output has 3 columns. What would you expect your output to be structured like if you had a hierarchy nested 4 (or more) deep? You cannot dynamically add more columns to an output unless you are going to use PL/SQL to dynamically build the query so you will need to have a fixed number of columns.

Comment: @MohamedAM-Hassan Updated